# Aggregating rows based on column values in pandas problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have this dataframe, df

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','A','B','B','C','C'], 'year': ['2013','2013','2014','2014', '2015','2015'],
    'type': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'cost': [30, 15, 20, 15, 30,25]})

df

   name year    type    cost
0   A   2013    a       30
1   A   2013    b       15
2   B   2014    a       20
3   B   2014    b       15
4   C   2015    a       30
5   C   2015    b       25
```

I want to get the totals of a and b per each name, so there would be a 3rd row for each name, to look like this.
my desired datarame:

```
  name  year    type        cost
0   A   2013    a           30
1   A   2013    b           15
2   A   2013    total_ab    45
3   B   2014    a           20
4   B   2014    b           15
5   B   2014    total_ab    35
6   C   2015    a           30
7   C   2015    b           25
8   C   2015    total_ab    55
```

I have tried this and cant quite achieve the result I want.

```
dft=df.groupby(['name', 'year']).agg({'cost': 'sum'}).reset_index()
#dft= df.groupby(['name', 'year', 'type']).agg({'cost': 'sum'})
Out:


  name  year    cost
0   A   2013    45
1   B   2014    35
2   C   2015    55
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: do you want "total_ab" to be dynamic to values? What if a value "c" exists for some of the groups? Would it be better to be "total_abc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a direct solution, but you can groupby and concat in two seprate operations like below

**update**: I have added `year` column to groupby as well.

```
rows_to_add = df[df.type.isin(['a', 'b'])]\
         .groupby(['name','year'], as_index=False)['cost'].sum()\
        .assign(type='total_ab')
```

Concatenate (and sort for names, as you suggested)

```
df = pd.concat([df, rows_to_add]).sort_values(['name'])
```

Also, you can exclude `df[df.type.isin(['a', 'b'])]` part if there isnnt any other type than `a` and `b`

Comment: thanks, I have just edited this. pd.concat might work!

Comment: I think you need to group by the name, year, and type columns

Comment: @PaulH thankyou for the comment, I re read the question but I think OP just want to group by name,

Comment: @bluetail, do you want to group by the year as well, also, did it helped?

Comment: yes, I do want it to look like I posted (my 2nd pic of the desired dataframe). I want to squeeze in this 'total_ab' row.

Comment: A.B, your solution works  : ) I've added .sort_values(['name'] at the end.

Comment: I have updated the answer for `years` column as well.

Comment: Ahh yes. You definitely don't want to group by the type column. My bad

Comment: @bluetail glad . feel free to upvote/accept-as-answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dataframe with your totals with `.groupby` and append it. I have also made the name of the total rows dynamic to the values within the `type` column within each group. This answer assumes you don't need to group by `type` as you have shown in the example you have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','A','B','B','C','C'], 'year': ['2013','2013','2014','2014', '2015','2015'],
    'type': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'cost': [30, 15, 20, 15, 30,25]})

df1 = df.groupby(['name', 'year'], as_index=False).agg({'type' : lambda x: list(x), 'cost' : 'sum'})
df1['type'] = 'total_' + df1['type'].map(''.join)
df = df.append(df1).sort_values(['name', 'year', 'type'])
df
Out[1]: 
  name  year      type  cost
0    A  2013         a    30
1    A  2013         b    15
0    A  2013  total_ab    45
2    B  2014         a    20
3    B  2014         b    15
1    B  2014  total_ab    35
4    C  2015         a    30
5    C  2015         b    25
2    C  2015  total_ab    55
```

Comment: everybody's comments are v helpful. I decided to amend my solution as  add_rows=df.groupby(['name', 'year'],as_index=False).agg({'cost': 'sum'}) , dft = pd.concat([df, add_rows]).sort_values(['name']), df_final = dft.replace(np.nan, 'total_ab', regex=True) :)

Comment: you can change `.agg({'cost': 'sum'})` to `['cost'].sum()`. It's more pythonic and a betterway to do groupby's when only summing one column. `.agg()` is usually for two or more columns.

Comment: thanks! 
I dont know who to vote for because both responses are helpful.

Comment: @bluetail in such cases you can flip a coin :)